# Associating EventToCommand with wp7 ApplicationBarIconButtons & ApplicationBarMenuItems

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm

Is there a way to Associate EventToCommand with wp7 ApplicationBarIconButtons & ApplicationBarMenuItems

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class that inherits from ApplicationBar and add that functionality there. Here is an example: [click](http://blog.humann.info/post/2010/08/27/How-to-have-binding-on-the-ApplicationBar.aspx).